# Add Authentication to One Controller

Tags: asp.net-core

I have two controllers, HomeController and AdminController. I want to let domainuser to access to AdminController while anonymous users to access to HomeController, how to do this in asp.net core mvc project? I am using .net core 7. I have tried to add policy in the program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
options.AddPolicy("DomainUserPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("DomainUser"));
});
```

and add policy to my AdminController:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "DomainUserPolicy")]
public class AdminController : Controller{ ...}
```

Now, I have this error message:

InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to authorize users you need to first authenticate users. So (like the error message suggests) you need to specify the default authentication scheme. For example you can use a cookie authentication scheme like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// ...

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("DomainUserPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("DomainUser"));
});

// ...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// ...

app.Run();
```

Then you need a login action where you will sign in users to create the cookie.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    // ...
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
        authProperties);
    // ...
}
```

There are many other ways to authenticate users, e.g. using bearer jwt tokens, Windows Authentication, etc.

Check documentation for more info: [Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Authorization works on the authenticated user, so I think the issue depends on the fact that you didn't set authentication.

As the exception message suggest, you must add an authentication  method.

You talk about domain users, so I imagine you want to authenticate users in a windows domain.
If this is the case, follow [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). I you host your app on IIS see the "IIS/IIS Express" paragraph, in other cases use the "Kestrel" solution.